# How to change the legend name when using qplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use qplot for a graph and try to change the legend name from "Temp" to "Average Temperature" it.. doesnt change. Do you know what could be wrong with my code:

```
qplot(Year,
       Temp,
       data = LithuaniaTemp,
       main = "Lithuania Average Temperature 1900-2013",
       geom = c("point","smooth")) +
 aes(colour = Temp) +
 scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red") +
 theme_fivethirtyeight() +
 scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend(title = "Average Temperature"))
```

Comment: You don't have a `scale_fill_continuous` in your data. So you're mapping a new legend title to an unused scale.

Comment: I think that qplot is deprecated. You should use ggplot.

Comment: aye, pls don't use `qplot()`. i spent a great deal of time nigh eradicating it from the official ggplot2 docs.

Comment: I also agree with other comments, ggplot has more flexibility and configurability. Once you will start using ggplot, you won't go back.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `labs` to set the legend title of each variable, e.g.

```
qplot(hp, disp, colour = factor(cyl), data = mtcars, geom = 'point') + 
    labs(colour = 'cylinders')
```

[image: plot with edited legend title]

Comment: Wow such a simple answer